# How to set the domain of x?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

```
a = 1/6 Log[x + 1] - 1/6 Log[x - 1]
b = 1/6 Log[(x + 1)/(x - 1)]
a == b
```

`a` and `b` should be equal, but `a==b` remains unevaluated.

1. Is this because `a` and `b` are indetermined for certain values of
   `x`?
2. How can I set the domain of `x` such that `a==b` gives `True`?
3. Is there another way to fix this without setting the domain?

Comment: `Simplify[PowerExpand[a == b]]`

Comment: And even if you specify the domain `Simplify[PowerExpand[a == b, Assumptions -> True], x \[Element] Reals]`, the answer is still not `True` as you claim: `x < -1 || x >= 1`, check your math :)

Comment: @swish But wolfram|alpha says it True: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot+(1%2F6)log(x%2B1)-(1%2F6)log(x-1)+%26+(1%2F6)log((x%2B1)%2F(x-1))

Comment: If you assume domain of reals, `Log` is undefined for negative numbers, you can't just compare the real part and say it's True.

Comment: @swish how can we set the domain of x such that a==b generates True?

Comment: `Simplify[a == b, Assumptions -> x < -1 || x >= 1]`

Comment: @swish Thanks! Why does PowerExpand work as well?

Comment: From documentation:
> PowerExpand converts Log[a^b] to bLog[a]. 
> PowerExpand in general disregards all issues of branches of multivalued functions, so may not preserve the numerical values of expressions.